# SSIS Project Deployment Model: assign sensitive parameter to a project connection string

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

We are using SSIS 2012 Project model and have project connection (manager) for all our packages, we create environment for dev, test and prod and created a variable "Connectionstring" inside each of them, the connection string is SQL Server authentication, so we have set the variable as sensitive to keep password hidden and then we configured the project connection manager to use the environment variable for the connection string. When we run the package we get the below error

"Unable to map an environment variable with the sensitive property set to True, to a parameter with the sensitive property set to False. Ensure that the property settings match"

I was unable to find a location where we can set the sensitive property for project connection manager, FYI when I uncheck the sensitive in the environment variable ,the packages run fine.

Am I missing something? I don't see a place where we can set the expression for project connection manger either, if that was the case at least I could have used the project parameters and set it to sensitive and configure the environment variable  to load into the parameter and in turn use parameter in the expression for project connection string.

Comment: Take a peek at [SSIS parametrize connection strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549821/ssis-parametrize-connection-strings/25551569#25551569) Does that cover your problem?

Comment: @billinkc that's something similar what we are doing but an extra step, making the variable in the environment as sensitive, if you still have that setup which you demonstrated in the above example, just change the variable in environment to sensitive and you will see the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was trying to parameterize the project connection but couldn't find it,but was able to figure it our later,posting answer so that some one else can find it like me, please "right click on project connection inside a package not directly under project connection managers and then click parameterize

Answer (score 2):

Use one environment variable for the connection string without the password, and create another environment variable for just the password and set it to Sensitive. Then map the password variable directly to the Password property in Connection Managers while configuring the project in SSMS (this doesn't require creating additional parameters).
The Password property is sensitive by design while the Connection String is not.

Answer (score 0):

So are you mapping the connection string to a project parameter? ( you would want to do this to take advantage on the configuration manger to change these parameters on the fly when you change the drop down for environment- Then set the project parameter variable to be sensitive and you should be good to go