# Cannot reference or call a SSIS project level parameter from Script Task

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, parameters, ssis

I am trying to replace the following VB.NET script used within the SSIS Script Task that setup the database connection string.

I need to externalize this connection string with a parameter value in SQL 2012 SSIS package Script Task. I created a project level parameter following this link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22194.use-ssis-variables-and-parameters-in-a-script-task.aspx

THIS IS THE CURRENT SCRIPT IN SCRIPT TASK:

```
Dim strConnectionString As String = "Data Source=GWAMZDEVDB02;Initial Catalog=DB_INT;Trusted_Connection=True;persist security info=True;packet size=4096;Connection Timeout=480"
```

THIS THE VB.NET CODE I WROTE TO REPLACE WITH PARAMETER :

```
int batchId = (int)Dts.Variables["$Project::batchId"].Value;
```

The parameter I setup in project level is:

`"$Project::GWAMZDEVDB02DB_INT_ConnectionString"`

I'm not great with coding. Can anyone please help me how to replace the "strConnectionString" value with parameter?

Greatly appreciate all of your inputs!

Thanks.

Syed

Comment: Actually more appropriate replacement code would be following: strConnectionString = Dts.Variables ["$Project::strConnectionString"].Value;

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a little confused. Two questions: (1) When you created your project level variable, did you name it "$Project::GWAMZDEVDB02DB_INT_ConnectionString"?  -- It should only be named "GWAMZDEVDB02DB_INT_ConnectionString" (2) In your script are you hoping to assign a value to the project level variable, or are you trying to read from it?

Comment: Why in the world are you using a script task to configure your database connection string? An Expression is cleaner and easier to maintain and for 2012+, [Connection Managers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549821/ssis-parametrize-connection-strings/25551569#25551569) should be configured within the Project Catalog and not through this old school approach. It's far easier to maintain and a host of other reasons