# Select the connection manager to be used in SSIS source by means of a parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

I created 3 different connection managers in an SSIS package, say connA connB and ConnC. How can I select the connection to use in an ado.net source using a parameter?
Thank you in advance
Carlo

Comment: Perhaps you could read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549821/ssis-parametrize-connection-strings/25551569#25551569, try the project deployment method and post back a specific issue, including exactly what you tried and why it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would go about it is to wrap your logic in a Script Task with a simple IF Else logic

Return your source via SQLDataAdapter and store in an object Variable.

This variable is then available as a table to read from in in any part of your package. Assuming that you assign the scope of the variable correctly.